# Error Code 413 - Uploading File to Server

Tags: ios, http, file-upload, afnetworking

So I am sending a JSON POST to the server of a byte array of the picture ranging from 8 MB to 18 MB. If I send anything around under 10 MB it's fine, but if I send bigger, I get error code 413 for Request Entity Too Large.

Is this a limitation of iOS as I checked with the backend guys and they said the limit is set to 50MBs.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is java-spring put this in your applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
  <property name="maxUploadSize" value="2000000"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: they are using Microsoft WCF Services

Comment: in web.config add <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="32768" />

Comment: check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911817/wcf-upload-large-images-as-wshttpbinding

Answer (score 0):

> It's possible that your test environment has these changes made so
>   that's one thing to look for/consider. People sometimes don't
>   overwrite configuration files during deployment so you may have an old
>   file there that just works.